# loop through a list and compare each item with another whole list

Tags: python, pandas, loops

**Table 1**

| Date | Prescribed |
| --- | --- |
| 16-05-2017 | Amlodipine [ Amlodipine | 10 mg | Tablet | OD | For 60 Days ], Cetirizine [ Cetirizine | 10 mg | Tablet | OD | For 5 Days ] |
| 15-05-2017 | CEFUROXIME[ ZINNAT | 500MG | Tablet | BID | For 7 Days ] |
| 17-05-2017 | Cetirizine [Cetirizine | 5 mg/5 mL | Syrup | BID | For 5 Days] |

**Table 2**

| Name | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Lisinopril (Lisinopril | 10 mg | Tablet) | CARDIOVASCULAR AGENT |
| Amlodipine (Amlodipine | 10 mg | Tablet) | CARDIOVASCULAR AGENT |
| Enoxaparin Sodium (80mg)(clexane 8000 iu | 80mg | 0) | CARDIOVASCULAR AGENT |

I want to be able to compare each item or row within the column['Prescribed'] with the whole of Table 2 column['Name'] to be able to create a column['category']row each row in Table 1.
Using pandas dataframes or any possible python method

### More Clarification(or Example)

**Table 1(From above)**

```
 test_text = "Amlodipine    [ Amlodipine     | 10 mg | Tablet | OD |  For 60 Days  ], Cetirizine    [ Cetirizine     | 10 mg | Tablet | OD |  For 5 Days  ]"
```

**Table 2(From above)**

```
comparison_list = [ 'Amlodipine (Amlodipine | 10 mg | Tablet)' ,  'Acetaminophen(Tylenol | 500mg| Tablet)' , 'Ibuprofen(Advil | 400mg | Tablet)']
```

**Expected outcome:**

```
Return True if 'Amlodipine' is in test_text
```

**To have a final table like below**
| Date | Prescribed | Result |
|:---- |:------:|:------:|
| 16-05-2017| Amlodipine [ Amlodipine | 10 mg | Tablet | OD |  For 60 Days  ], Cetirizine [ Cetirizine | 10 mg | Tablet | OD |  For 5 Days  ]|True|
| 15-05-2017  | CEFUROXIME[ ZINNAT | 500MG | Tablet | BID | For 7 Days  ]  |False|
| 17-05-2017  | Cetirizine [Cetirizine | 5 mg/5 mL | Syrup | BID | For 5 Days]|False|

**Below are some methods i have tried.**

```
for i in table1['Prescribed']:
    split_data = i.split(",")
        for b in split_data:
            if any(str(b) in s for s in table2['Name']):
                print('true')
            elif str(b) in table2['Name']:
                print('perfect')
            else:
                print('false')
```

> Output:

```
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
```

**Without splitting text:**

```
for i in table1['Prescribed']:
      if any(str(i) in s for s in table2['Name']):
          print('true')
      elif str(i) in table2['Name']:
          print('perfect')
      else:
          print('false')
```

> Outcome:

```
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
```

If there is any solution to this, i would be happy to know. Suggestions on how to do it neater is also appreciated. And if there is a link or book to read concerning how to go about this too, i would be happy to know about them .

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k). Please [read this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as to why it is discouraged.

Comment: It seems that you have problems with your data format. Lets call A 
an splited value it will be something like A ="Amlodipine [Amlodipine   | 10mg | Tablet | OD | For 30 Days]"
thile for the other table you will have (invented) B= "Amlodipine (Amlodipine   | 10mg | Tablet)". So you 
will never have A in B neither B in A cause their formats are diferents.
It's seems that you have to preprocess your data before start searching coincidences.

Comment: Thank you very much @AkshaySehgal on the advice concerning the images. I have made the necessary edits. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @UlisesBussi. I understand i need to clean the data before the analysis. The data is huge and i have been looking for ways to automate that process through code. However i thought there might be a simpler way since i have been trying to solve this for a few days now. Trying to learn regex to help with cleaning of the data. Thanks very much for your comment.

Comment: quick question, are you trying to match just the drug name or the complete dosage etc

Comment: @PhxIT, please check my updated answer. it works on the data that you have provided and should be quite fast to run since it uses vectorized str methods, instead of iterating over each row one by one.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal just the drug name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to extract the drug names from the `table2['Name']` and then use that as a comparison list to find if ANY of those occur in the table1['Prescription'].

If this is what you want, then try this -

1. Use vectorized `str` functions like `replace`, `split` and `strip` to extract the unique drug names for your comparison list.
2. Next use `'|'.join()` to connect these unique drugs with a `OR` connector to find if any of those exist in the `table1['Prescription]'` with the use of another vectorized `str` function `str.contains`

> 1. NOTE 1: Using apply functions for working with string is not as efficient as using `str` methods in pandas.

> 2. NOTE 2: The regex `[\(\[].*?[\)\]]` is for removing the text inside the `()` or `[]` brackets and returning only the text outside, which is this case is the name of the drugs. Feel free to replace it with anything else.

```
#STEP 1: Get unique drugs from the table2
unique_drugs = table2['Name'].str.replace('[\(\[].*?[\)\]]','',regex=True)\
                             .str.split(',')\
                             .explode()\
                             .str.strip()\
                             .unique()

## unique_drugs : array(['Lisinopril', 'Amlodipine', 'Enoxaparin Sodium'], dtype=object)

# STEP 2: FIND MATCHING DRUGS IN THE DATA
table1['flag'] = table1['Prescribed'].str.contains('|'.join(unique_drugs))
print(table1)
```

```
         Date                                         Prescribed   flag
0  16-05-2017  Amlodipine [ Amlodipine | 10 mg | Tablet | OD ...   True
1  15-05-2017  CEFUROXIME[ ZINNAT | 500MG | Tablet | BID | Fo...  False
2  17-05-2017  Cetirizine [Cetirizine | 5 mg/5 mL | Syrup | B...  False
```